# Почему не создается элемент?

Tags: javascript

```js
var gg = [];
var boy = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var chekparent = boy.parentNode;
for(var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
  gg[j] = document.createElement('div');
  gg[j].className = j + 'avtomatTest';
  chekparent.insertBefore(gg[j], boy);
}
```

Comment: Что за переменная `dontCry`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko старая переменная, но сути не меняет. Все равно не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код работает и вставляет элементы.

```js
var gg = [];
var boy = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var chekparent = boy.parentNode;
for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
  gg[j] = document.createElement('div');
  gg[j].textContent = j;
  gg[j].className = j + 'avtomatTest';
  chekparent.insertBefore(gg[j], boy);
}
```

Comment: спасибо).дело в индексе у меня до этого  в head был подключен jquery, поэтому надо было поставить индекс 1 .

Comment: @Hungry какой индекс вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: у меня есть два тэга скрипт- 1 в head другой в body . Я про индекс в строчке: var boy = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

Comment: @Hungry что бы не было проблем и правильность работы скрипта не зависела от положения тега `script` используйте id и соответственно метод `document.getElementById('scriptId')`.